# Where do i put a file I want to reference in an openscad project?

Tags: cad, openscad

Im using the 'import' command but i'm not sure where to actually place the file in my file system. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is you just need to have it in the same directory as the scad file, either that or code in the full path if it's outside that folder.